# How to start Spark Thrift Server on Datastax Enterprise (fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ...LogDivertAppender.setWriter)?

Tags: java, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

When I am trying to run datastax spark-sql-thriftserver, I am getting these errors:

```
dse spark-sql-thriftserver start \
  --conf spark.cores.max=10 \
  --conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
  --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001
```

> Spark Command: /opt/jdk1.8.0_112/jre//bin/java -cp
>   /etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/spark/jars/*:/etc/dse/hadoop2-client/
>   -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/dse/hadoop2-client/lib/native:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin:
>   -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -Dguice_include_stack_traces=OFF -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=32174 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader
>   -Dlogback.configurationFile=/etc/dse/spark/logback-spark.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Ddse.client.configuration.impl=com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.HadoopBasedClientConfiguration
>   -Dderby.stream.error.method=com.datastax.bdp.derby.LogbackBridge.getLogger
>   -Xmx1024M org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.executor.memory=2g --conf spark.cores.max=10 --class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2
>   spark-internal --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001
>   ======================================== WARN 2017-05-07 22:21:55 org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some
>   configuration may not take effect. ERROR 2017-05-07 22:22:04
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start 
>   or submit Spark application java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.setWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)V
>   at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.(LogDivertAppender.java:166)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.initOperationLogCapture(OperationManager.java:85)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.init(OperationManager.java:63)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$class.initCompositeService(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLSessionManager.initCompositeService(SparkSQLSessionManager.scala:36)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLSessionManager.init(SparkSQLSessionManager.scala:58)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$class.initCompositeService(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIService.initCompositeService(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:39)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIService.init(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:62)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$$anonfun$initCompositeService$1.apply(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>   ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ReflectedCompositeService$class.initCompositeService(SparkSQLCLIService.scala:79)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.initCompositeService(HiveThriftServer2.scala:272)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.init(HiveThriftServer2.scala:292)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:94)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DseSparkSubmit$$runMain(DseSparkSubmit.scala:730)
>   ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(DseSparkSubmit.scala:175)
>   ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.submit(DseSparkSubmit.scala:200)
>   ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.main(DseSparkSubmit.scala:109)
>   ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:74)
>   ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
>   [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0] ERROR 2017-05-07 22:22:15
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveThriftServer2.scala:85)
>   ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:215)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1953)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na] at 
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:187)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:177)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6] at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
>   [hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]

Relevant part of the log:
`ERROR 2017-05-07 22:22:04
org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start or submit Spark application java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.setWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)V at
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.(LogDivertAppender.java:166) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]`

I have opscenter 6.1 and dse 5.1

====

### Update 1

files in /usr/share/dse/hadoop2-client/lib/native

> libhadoop.a  libhadoop.so  libhadoop.so.1.0.0  libhadooppipes.a 
>   libhadooputils.a  libhdfs.a  libhdfs.so  libhdfs.so.0.0.0

files in /usr/share/dse/spark/jars

> empty

files in /usr/share/dse/spark/lib

> JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar                    commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
>   httpclient-4.5.2.jar                      jersey-server-2.22.2.jar
>   netty-3.9.8.Final.jar                reflectasm-1.10.1.jar
>   spark-sketch_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar
>   commons-io-2.5.jar               httpcore-4.4.4.jar
>   jline-2.14.2.jar                  noggit-0.6.jar
>   scala-compiler-2.11.8.jar
>   spark-sql_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar
>   commons-lang3-3.4.jar            httpmime-4.4.1.jar
>   joda-convert-1.2.jar              objenesis-2.1.jar
>   scala-xml_2.11-1.0.4.jar
>   spark-streaming_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar 
>   commons-math3-3.4.1.jar          ivy-2.4.0.jar
>   joda-time-2.9.3.jar               opencsv-2.3.jar
>   scalap-2.11.8.jar
>   spark-tags_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar
>   compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar           jackson-annotations-2.5.3.jar
>   jodd-core-3.5.2.jar               oro-2.0.8.jar
>   scalatest_2.11-2.2.6.jar
>   spark-unsafe_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar avro-1.7.7.jar
>   core-1.1.2.jar                   jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   jpam-1.1.jar                      osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
>   snappy-0.2.jar
>   spire-macros_2.11-0.7.4.jar avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar
>   datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar    jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.11.jar        paranamer-2.8.jar
>   solr-solrj-6.0.1.0.1596.jar
>   spire_2.11-0.7.4.jar avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar
>   datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar      jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.5.3.jar
>   json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar       parquet-column-1.7.0.jar
>   spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.11-2.0.1.jar  stax-api-1.0.1.jar
>   bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar              datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
>   javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
>   json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.11.jar    parquet-common-1.7.0.jar
>   spark-catalyst_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar                    stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
>   breeze-macros_2.11-0.11.2.jar         derby-10.10.2.0.jar
>   javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar                jsr166e-1.1.0.jar
>   parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar           spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar
>   stream-2.7.0.jar breeze_2.11-0.11.2.jar
>   eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar   javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
>   jta-1.1.jar                       parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar 
>   spark-graphx_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar                      super-csv-2.2.0.jar
>   calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar  hive-beeline-1.2.1.spark2.jar
>   javolution-5.5.1.jar                      jtransforms-2.4.0.jar
>   parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar
>   spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar
>   univocity-parsers-2.1.1.jar calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar
>   hive-cli-1.2.1.spark2.jar        jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
>   jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar           parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar
>   spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar                        unused-1.0.0.jar
>   calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar   hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar
>   jersey-client-2.22.2.jar                  kryo-3.0.3.jar
>   parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar      spark-launcher_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar
>   velocity-1.7.jar cassandra-driver-mapping-3.1.4.jar
>   hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar       jersey-common-2.22.2.jar
>   libfb303-0.9.3.jar                parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar
>   spark-mllib-local_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar
>   woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar chill-java-0.8.0.jar
>   hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar  jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar
>   mail-1.4.7.jar                    pmml-model-1.2.15.jar
>   spark-mllib_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar
>   xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar chill_2.11-0.8.0.jar
>   hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar
>   jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar 
>   mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar  pmml-schema-1.2.15.jar
>   spark-network-common_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
>   hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar        jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar
>   metrics-json-3.1.2.jar            py4j-0.10.1.jar
>   spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar commons-codec-1.10.jar
>   hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar          jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar
>   minlog-1.3.0.jar                  pyrolite-4.13.jar
>   spark-repl_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar

---

### Update 2

I have a DSE 5.0 installation also, but it also does not contain any apache-log4j jars and the spark-sql-thrift-server works fine.

After placing `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` in `/usr/share/dse/spark/lib` I am getting the error (see https://pastebin.com/KjgsEhnw for the entire log):

```
Spark Command: /opt/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -cp /etc/dse/spark/:/usr/share/dse/spark/jars/*:/etc/dse/hadoop2-client/ -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/dse/hadoop2-client/lib/native:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin: -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -Dguice_include_stack_traces=OFF -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=32174 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader -Dlogback.configurationFile=/etc/dse/spark/logback-spark.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Ddse.client.configuration.impl=com.datastax.bdp.transport.client.HadoopBasedClientConfiguration -Dderby.stream.error.method=com.datastax.bdp.derby.LogbackBridge.getLogger -Xmx1024M org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 spark-internal
========================================
WARN  2017-05-19 14:11:31 org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect.
WARN  2017-05-19 14:11:36 org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Unexpected exception caught.
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104) [hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503) [hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:189) [spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:247) [spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForExecution(HiveUtils.scala:250) [spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:88) [spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala) [spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6.jar:2.0.2.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DseSparkSubmit$$runMain(DseSparkSubmit.scala:730) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(DseSparkSubmit.scala:175) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.submit(DseSparkSubmit.scala:200) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.main(DseSparkSubmit.scala:109) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:74) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala) [dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166) ~[jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap
    at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.<init>(Hierarchy.java:97) ~[apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:na]
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82) ~[apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:na]
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104) ~[apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.util.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:49) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.datanucleus.util.NucleusLogger.getLoggerInstance(NucleusLogger.java:237) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.util.NucleusLogger.<clinit>(NucleusLogger.java:205) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginRegistryFactory.newPluginRegistry(PluginRegistryFactory.java:74) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:61) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createPluginManager(PluginManager.java:427) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:266) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225) ~[datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:na]
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.or.RendererMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Comment: extra's jar didn't help, but I was missing log4j jar as well, I copied it from a fresh download of spark and placed it in my DSE 5.1, it now seems to work fine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, If you can frame the comment as an answer I would like to award you the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.(LogDivertAppender.java:166)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/java/org/apache/hive/service/cli/operation/LogDivertAppender.java#L166) shows the following line:

```
setWriter(writer);
```

that leads to `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` that I can see in my Spark installation as `jars/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar`.

I don't see `jars/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` in the list of jars that seems *somehow* related with the affected missing method.

My recommendation would be to take `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` from some other Spark download and place it under `/usr/share/dse/spark/lib` or even `/usr/share/dse/spark/jars` as it's currently empty.

I found it available at [Download Apache Extras Companion™ for Apache log4j™](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/download.html).

That may or may not require a corresponding log4j jar.

I'd recommend reporting an issue to the DSE support.